# how to implement xml in Spring DAO based application?

Tags: java, xml, spring, oxm

In my project, I have used JSF and SpringDAO and webservices.
I am calling various webservices which returns with XML and I need to parse and use this XML.
So my question is... What can I use?

Is there anything in Spring by default that I can check?
Do I need to separately parse my content and use it through core java code?
or any thing else...

What can be done in this case?

Comment: No I don't have that. As well I don't have any idea regarding XSD even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two classical XML Parser are available based on SAX and DOM. Read here for more on [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/xmljava/ch03.pdf).

Spring also supports **Object/XML mapping**. Which is,

> A new feature, as of Spring 3.0, is the O/X Mapper. The concept of an O/X mapper is not new. The O stands for Object. The X stands for XML. The idea is to translate a Java object (almost always a plain old Java object or POJO) into an XML document and vice versa.
>
> So, for example, you might have a simple bean with a few attributes and you have a business need to translate that Java object into an XML document. Spring's O/X Mapper can handle that for you. If the reverse is true (that is, you need to take an XML document and translate it into a simple Java bean), Spring's O/X Mapper can also handle that.

Read an article [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-springXOM/) or API [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/oxm.html).

This is really interesting and can hide the complexity of XML parsing in you code. Choose it if you can.

Comment: Yup dardo, ManuPK's answer is really awsome. I am checking on same. Hope I can create demo and implement it.